# What does 'redact password' mean?

Tags: database, security

Reading InfluxDB docs, I found this note:

> Note: InfluxDB redacts passwords when you enable authentication.

Link: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/administration/authentication_and_authorization

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snippet

> Note: InfluxDB redacts passwords when you enable authentication.

means that if your InfluxDB instance has authentication enabled, when you use the HTTP API, InfluxDB will not include the username and password you supplied in any of its logs.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the following explanation/definition of the word **redact**

"**To redact is to edit, or prepare for publishing**. Frequently, a redacted document, such as a memo or e-mail message, has simply had personal (or possibly actionable) information deleted or blacked out; as a consequence, redacted is often used to describe documents from which sensitive information has been expunged."

"Expunged": To erase, remove completely.

Via: http://searchcio.techtarget.com/definition/redact

In this case, the basic logic behind this is that when we're editing a database, we have to **redact** the proposed requirement.

In other words, just like the definition implies, we "prepare to publish" a said variable using a proposed **authentication**.

Hope this helped!